# How to fix perspective distort of objects in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photography

When doing product photography, how can I fix the perspective distortion caused by my lens in Photoshop? For example, when photographing books. The first drawing is the result I get with my lens, and the second is what I would like to make. [image]

Comment: Probably easier to retake the photo. Stand further back and zoom in.

Comment: I can't retake them.

Comment: *Filter > Lens Correction*

Comment: @rachel1 and this is why professional photographers get paid. Ultimately they save you money since you dont have to do so much fixing.

Answer (score 5):

Make your picture a square file > Convert it into a layer > Increase the canvas size (on the picture the gray area)

[image: block]

Activate the picture layer > Go to Menu **Filter** > **Lens Correction**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop's Edit > Transform > Distort can give a partial result:

[image]

This is also rotated a little. Without having 3D information it's not possible to achieve arbitary projection changes

An exactly rectangular object can in theory be fixed more perfectly by distorting the visible sides one by one. The result will be mediocore at best because the seam areas in practice are more or less rounded in the object.

[image]